# Run latest version of Websocket code on older version of Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websocket, tomcat7

I have written a WebSocket using `@ServerEndpoint` as extending `WebSocketServlet` is deprecated on latest version on JavaEE.

Bu I have to run this code on **`Tomcat-7.0.34`**. Later I figured out that Tomcat started supporting `@ServerEndpoint` from version **`Tomcat 7.0.47`**.

I can not upgrade the version of Tomcat. Is there any way to run my code latest Websocket on older version of Tomcat?